# How to detect that download is done whether by Browser or Download Manager on Android OS phones from HTML 5 web portal?

Tags: php, android, html, web

I am trying to make a html mobile web portal that let users download files.

But I want to detect that that the download is done through Download Manager or Browser?

How to do that as User Agent is also same for both on many devices?

Comment: They aren't the same user agent. AndroidDownloadManager

Comment: If the user agent is the same, it's the same. You only get an HTTP request, which can be made to look identical to any other HTTP request, regardless of the origin. What's the use case for this distinction?

Comment: No i want to distinct it but don't know how to, @Sam all phones do not have user agent as 'AndroidDownloadManager'. Many have same as browser.

Comment: I've they have the same as the browser,  than you u have to handle it the same way. The attribute "user agent" is to identify witch programm requests your page.

Comment: Dear Sam, when the first download is hit by browser then it forward the control to android download manager. So, my motive is that second time if the download manager hits then i will allow download else i won't.